Bluetooth not working on a MacBook Pro 2017
I have a Mac Book Pro 2017 13" (Intel) and made the change to Ubuntu 24.04LTS the sound and Bluetooth are not working. I tried
sudo apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic and sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tobhe/asahi-testing to try some of the options I saw in the forums, but none have worked.
If someone has another option will be most appreciated.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! "apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic"? - apt will not work without sudo neither will all the other commands you gave on a single line. Please Edit your question and provide (in order) the exact commands you used.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

check out https://t2linux.org for drivers for intel macs

The Bluetooth problem was solved using this https://github.com/leifliddy/macbook12-bluetooth-driver

Follow the steps:
PART 1
$ sudo apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic

$ git clone https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro.git

$ cd snd_hda_macbookpro/

$ sudo ./install.cirrus.driver.sh

reboot

PART 2 (In case still not working)
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio

$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio

$ mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/new_pulse_conf

reboot

